# How to know the priority value of phone inbox

Tags: android, sms, inbox

I am trying to intercept the SMSs and abort its broadcast. I have read several posts and I think there are an agreement in that the abortBroadcast along with other code do the work. The only thing that i think there is some disagreement is on the value that **android:priority** should take. I want to know the priority value of the phone inbox and set a higher value on my android:priority, or, even better, change its value to a lower value and set my android:priority value to a higher value.

A great THANKS to all contributors of this GREAT forum.
I hope I can contribute with some answers soon but so far I can contribute only with questions...